# Recover Visual Studio installation from external hard disk

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, windows-8.1

I recently had to replace my hard disk on my laptop, which contained my Visual Studio installation. When the new hard disk was added, unfortunately the person involved in setup has put Windows 8.1 on an internal SSD (I am using Dell XPS) and made this the system drive -- since this is ~30GB only, re-installing Visual Studio is not an option it seems, as my understanding is that even if the install path is changed to the new hard drive, VS will still need significant space on the system drive (I have ~6GB left).

My old hard drive is being used as an external drive, and it seems all the data is fine, and can see that the VC compilers work fine via the command line. My question is, if there is a method by which I can get the Visual Studio installation up and running on my old hard drive(external), as all the components needed are present -- is there a config file or some such that I could use, and manually enter the registry information to make it work? Is there anything else I could do?

Comment: No. A *lot* of the settings are stored in the registry and many components are stored in C:\Windows.

Comment: The components are all there, already in place, since the Windows installation is still there on the external drive, but yeah I guess without the registry entries....all the command line tools along with the compilers are working though...so its only the GUI component I guess.